# running SSRS remotely

Tags: .net, reporting-services

I am developing a window forms application that is expected to display an SSRS report on the UI.

A brief background:

1. We have a 3 - tier architecture in place. We are using WCF.
2. We have permissioning in place, where in users have access to specific reports.
3. By Default, we have a daily SSRS job that runs and generates the relevant reports and saves the output reports in a folder. The reports are manually read, verified and dispatched to relevant distribution list (since we are in the initial phase of development). In addition as mentioned earlier, we are expected to provide ad hoc generation of reports via a win form application, for which we can use the Report Viewer control. However, we do not want the GUI directly connecting to the remote reporting server, since user permissioing is driven of user defined tables and so want the all calls form the GUI being routed via our App Server.

Is is possible to remotely manage an SSRS job. I hope to manage it from the App Server.If not, could you please share your suggestions of how I can circumvent the problem?

Answer (score 0):

We're attempting something similar, although in our case it's a web application. Can't you check the permissions in the winforms application and only allow the ReportViewer display the relevant reports which the user has access to, or am I oversimplifying?

Comment: We can check for the permissions, but we would like to have a view of the SSRS report generation process, to know whether the report has been generated successfully and we would also like to specify the output path for the report, so in effect apart from permissioning we need to have more control over the input paramters. Hope that makes sense.